# 'Hide initial item' setting of fc not working when used in editable format block of views

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-field-collection

Not sure if issue I am having is just related to fc or combination of fc and views.

We are using quicktabs with multiple views. One of the view (block with Editable table format) has editable field collection field called employment history that is part of user profile. Even though I have checked both checkboxes 'Hide initial item' and 'Hide empty item' the field collection item in views preview as well on tab displays initial form instead of just showing "Add more item" button.

Note: The display of FC on normal user edit page is as expected . i.e initial form is hidden (if no employment history is added) and button is shown if you want to add emp history.

When debugged found out that in field_collection.module "hide_initial_item" is showing false  in both field_collection_field_widget_form and field_collection_field_attach_form function.

Has anyone came across issue of initial empty item (first item form ) of field collection showing when used in views ?

Comment: You should post your code here so we can help you figure this out.  Please read this guide for asking a good Question and edit this accordingly: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: @Graham - we haven't added any custom code to this change. Everything is in config and mainly done using FC, views and quick tabs module. Which part of code would you want me to post here to help it further investigate ?

Comment: Also I have uploaded screenshots [link]https://www.drupal.org/node/2852783 - if it helps